# How to paste from clipboard in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, paste

I am using cypress to test the flow of my application. At this point it just opens an account and follows the flow as a user would. At a point I copy a link and would like to follow that link.

The issue I have is that the link changes with every test that I run and I don't know what the link is until its been copied.
When the test finishes, I would like to paste that link in the browser and make sure that the page does exist.

I cant seem to find a way to paste from my clipboard. Is there a way to do this ? My next test basically needs to start with

```
cy.visit('paste');
```

Ive tried doing

```
cy.visit('{Ctrlv}');
```

But that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you want to do is use `cy.request()` to test the link exist.

`cy.visit(pasted-link-here)` might be tricky if the link you need to test is outside the original domain, but `cy.request()` can give you a status code.

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
  win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then(urlFromClipboard => {
    cy.request(urlFromClipboard)
      .then(response => expect(response.status).to.eq(200))
  })
})
```

Actually, see [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Requirements)

> cy.request() requires that the response status code be 2xx or 3xx

so you could just use this

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
  win.navigator.clipboard.readText().then(urlFromClipboard => {
    cy.request(urlFromClipboard)
  })
})
```

and the test will fail if status code is a failure code.

Comment: Thank you ! This worked for what I was trying to achieve. I was told now that I do need to make some assertions on this page... Which I cant do unless it loads, so now Im back to square one #MovingTargetLand :/

Comment: Apologies I got last comment backwards - You can set `failOnStatusCode: false` option to allow the response to be checked even if it fails - see [How to test a bad request in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56853989/16695029)